# How do I remove data from a double nested schema in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, express, mongoose

First of all pardon me if this question have been asked dozen times. I followed some of the responses to them but still didn't achieve what I wanted. So I have this mongoose schema of posts, with comments as a key containing an array of sub comment objects. I am trying to remove one sub comment from the `postComments` array, however it doesn't work. [image: Image of my collection]

I'm trying to remove the first object in postComments array based on the comment Id.

My delete comment function:

```
export const deleteCommentOnPost = async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id; // post id
  const { userId, commentId } = req.body;

  try {
    const post = await PostModel.findById(id);
    const sp = post.postComments;

    post.update({ _id: id }, { $pull: { sp: { _id: commentId } } });
    res.status(200).json('Comment deleted successfilly');
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error);
  }
};
```

My json body request:

```
{
  "userId" : "63bc8c8fd4368837fbc9354b",
  "commentId" : "63f555f709ae0225a7a9b76e"
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after lots of trial and error, I finally achieved what I wanted, not with mongoose query though, but still gets the job done.

```
export const deleteCommentOnPost = async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id; // post id
  const { userId, commentId } = req.body;

  try {
    const post = await PostModel.findById(id);
    const sp = post.postComments;
    sp.id(commentId).remove();
    await post.save();
    res.status(200).json('Comment deleted successfilly');
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error);
  }
};
```

Mongoose doc for [Removing subdocs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#removing-subdocs)